# Do I use set or if?

Tags: batch-file

Would I use set or if to change some words around? I want to make it so if certain characters are types it will change them. If the letter is typed it will be changed to a different one. Ex. A=u t=a so if at would be ua

```
@echo off

title DNA to mRNA/tRNA
color A

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:start
cls
echo Please select what you would like to do.
echo (1) mRNA
echo (2) tRNA
echo (3) Exit

choice /C 123

if ERRORLEVEL 3 exit
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto tRNA
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto mRNA


:mRNA
cls
echo Enter the DNA sequence.
set /p mRNA=mRNA:
set a=u
set t=a
set c=g
set g=c
echo %mRNA%
pause
goto start


:tRNA
cls
echo Enter the mRNA sequence.

set /p tRNA=tRNA:
set u=a
set a=u
set g=c
set c=g
echo %tRNA%
pause
goto start
```

Comment: please clarify your question. also, please correctly format your text. have you seen the toolbars on the textfield where you wrote your question?

Comment: I just want to know which one Would be the best to change multiple characters typed in

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: There is basically only two commands you can really use to do string manipulation.  `SET` and `FOR /F`.  The `IF` command just compares values.

Comment: remove the `hold` status please.. i may have have an answer

Comment: `for %%a in ("a=u" "t=a" "c=X" "g=c" "X=g") do set "mRNA=!mRNA:%%~a!"` with `EnableDelayedExpansion`...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

title DNA to mRNA/tRNA
color A

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the sets of conversions
set conv[1]="a=u" "t=a" "c=1" "g=c" "1=c"
set conv[2]="u=2" "a=u" "2=a" "g=2" "c=g" "2=c"
set "opt[1]=mRNA"
set "opt[2]=tRNA"
set "opt[3]=Exit"

:start
cls
echo Please select what you would like to do.
for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do echo (%%i) !opt[%%i]!

choice /C 123
if ERRORLEVEL 3 exit

set "replace=!conv[%errorlevel%]!"
echo/
echo Enter the original sequence.
set /p "DNA=!opt[%errorlevel%]!: "
for %%a in (%replace%) do set "DNA=!DNA:%%~a!"
echo Conversion: %DNA%
pause
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

Aacini almost has it right, but I don't think the replacements are quite right.

Here's my version, which translates all the letters to numbers first, then translates all the numbers to their corresponding letters.

This avoids convering all the `A` to `U`, and then translating all the `U` (both original and newly translated) back into `A`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mDNA=ugac

for  %%a in ("a=1" "c=2" "g=3" "u=4" "1=u" "2=g" "3=c" "4=a") do (
    set "mDNA=!mDNA:%%~a!"
)

echo Translated pattern is %mDNA%
```